# GPUImage presents vertical black bars when using iPhone front camera

Tags: ios, camera, gpuimage

I am trying to integrate GPUImage into my iPhone app to take photos with real-time filters. But I found an annoying problem: when I use the front camera to take photos, there are always some vertical black bars in the result image.

- Rear camera never has this problem;
- It has nothing to do with filters, I have tried without any filter.

First I think it has something to do with my iPhone hardware, then I searched on internet, other developers have met the same problem (with no solution).

see image here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPAJ9.jpg

Comment: This is a known bug in AV Foundation when using texture caches in iOS 5.0 (fixed in iOS 6.0). How old is the GPUImage framework code you're using? This should have been fixed in the framework for a while, as Kalli Dalli is pointing to a fix I implemented 6 months ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help you out:

> I had the same exact problem. In the GPUImageStillCamera.m, I commented out "[self captureOutput:photoOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:imageSampleBuffer fromConnection:[[photoOutput connections] objectAtIndex:0]];" and now the glitches are gone. That's the only way I was able to fix the problem without forcing GPUImageOpenGLESContext's +supportsFastTextureUpload to return NO.

for more see: [here](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/108)

Comment: That works! Thanks! I cannot vote up, not enough reputation :(

Comment: np, do it later if you like.